# What are the ways I can contribute to Ethereum?

Tags: blockchain, dapps, dapp-development

I'd like to know more about how to contribute, both on a technical and non technical perspective

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could participate in / contribute to the [homestead documentation initiative](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/42vuik/homestead_documentation_initiative/)
see the [scoping out discussion here](https://gitter.im/ethereum/homestead-guide)

you could contribute both tech and non tech answers / commentary in the Ethereum Forum

You could run a wallet, buy a few Ethers for it & provide technical or empirical feedback (or both) on that experience here

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. Run a node
2. Mine the Blockchain
3. Be an evangelist

And there are plenty other ways, like provide support in forums, and most probably buy ethereum (ETH)